# Buffon's problem revisited with disk and equilateral triangles

Tags: probability

A floor is marked with three sets of straight lines forming equilateral triangles. Let $d$ be the common sidelength of these triangles. A circular disk with radius $r$ is thrown on them.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIh72.png  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIh72.png)

a.  Find the expression for probability of the disk touching any line as a function of $d$ and $r$.

b.  If $d = 50$ cm, what value of $r$ will give a 25% probability of disk crossing a line?

Comment: You could ask yourself where in a triangle the center would land to not touch any line.

Comment: I know but I am unable to solve it help please if you can.

Comment: Do you agree my modifications? In particular "could you help me please" is not a title (otherwise everybody could take this title!). For Buffon's needle see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon's_needle)

Comment: Thanks can you solve it for me please

Comment: I will not "solve it for you". What we do in Math SE is to help people to find themselves solutions. See my coming "answer".

Answer (score 1):

Base your reasoning on where the center of the disk is when the disk doesn't intersect any triangle ABC (in fact, when it is included in a certain triangle ).

Could you describe the set of positions of these centers such that there is no intersection of the disk with a triangle: you should find a triangle EFG...

What is the ratio $r$ of its area compared to the area of the equilateral triangle including it ? Why is this ratio $r$ the probability you are looking for?

Beware, this is only when $r$ is rather small compared to $d$...

[image]